# How do I convert an existing *Git* repo to a treeless clone?

Tags: git, git-clone

I have a few big repos, that were cloned to build packages. I'd like to reduce their sizes.

I know I can do a treeless clone instead, via `GITFLAGS="--filter=tree:0"`. However I have backup snapshots.

I'd like to run this on existing repos, to avoid introducing any new files. How do I do this?

(Note this setting breaks builds of some packages, that have parts that point to particular commits.)

Comment: I don't think it's possible so far. Otherwise, the partial clone should've been able to work without server support.

Comment: Consider using [git-lfs](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Tutorial#git-lfs-tutorial) and/or [BFG Repo Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) to reduce the repository sizes. Anything which points at a particular commit ID should instead point at a tag.

Comment: @Schwern Note the context is for source repos that are there to build the packages. I do not own them. In fact the build scripts do use tags.